# Give php permission to create files without permissions error

Tags: php, nginx, ubuntu-14.04

When using the `move_uploaded_file()` function in PHP I get the error:

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(...): failed to open stream: Permission denied in ...

On my server I have the `public_html` permissions like:

```
drwxr-sr-x 7 user www-data 4096 Apr 27 17:48 public_html
```

Which is recursively through-out the directory.

Have you got any ideas why this might not be working? Or what I can do to help me find out why this is not working.

---

## The system

The server is actually a cluster where the files are on a NAS and the php is on the cluster. I am performing all the permission commands on the device of the NAS as that is where the user FTP's to.

Comment: You didn't give the paths in the error so have a look at `upload_tmp_dir` and `sys_temp_dir` in php.ini or in the additional ini files.  Are you actually uploading files or just trying to move existing ones?

Comment: `upload_tmp_dir` has been commented out (so using default) Do I need to create it? When I `echo sys_get_temp_dir();` I get `/tmp`

Comment: `sys_temp_dir` has not been found in the php.ini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User www-data can not write to public_html directory. Use chmod on your public_html to give www-data write permission:

```
chmod 775 public_html -R
```

Comment: I could have sworn I have tried that a million times!! But it seems to have worked. This is the first time I did it on the actual cluster rather than the NAS... Do you think that had something to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

First off, the SUID and SGID only make sense when used with executable files.

From http://www.codecoffee.com/tipsforlinux/articles/028.html :

> **SUID (Set User ID) Bit**
>
> [...] in case I have an application whose owner is ' root ' and it has its SUID bit set, then when I run this application as a normal user, that application would still run as root. Since the SUID bit tells Linux that the the User ID root is set for this application and whenever this application executes it must execute as if root was executing it (since root owns this file)
>
> **SGID (Set Group ID) bit**
>
> Just like SUID, setting the SGID bit for a file sets your group ID to the file's group while the file is executing. IT is really useful in case you have a real multi-user setup where users access each others files. As a single homeuser I haven't really found a lot of use for SGID. But the basic concept is the same as the SUID, the files whose SGID bit are set would be used as if they belong to that group rather than to that user alone.

So if none of your web files need to be executed as a normal process, it is best to leave the SGID alone.

Finally if you didn't change your web server's security context, it (*most probably*, as you didn't mention any paths) tries to move a file which is located in a directory `www-data` can only *read*. To move a file you need write access to the directories where the file *is* and *will be* moved to. So `www-data` should be given *write* access to

1. the directory where the file lands in the first place (by default:  `/tmp`, in which case nothing's to be done)
2. the destination directory, where it is intended to be moved to.